# cannot use beforeEach with the inject function

Tags: angularjs, karma-mocha, angular-mock

This is from the karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
      frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
      files: [
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'public/ng-app/module.js',
        'public/ng-app/**/*.js',
        'test/ng/**/*.spec.js'
      ],
  ...
```

I am trying to use the beforeEach function with inject like this:

```
describe('my.test', function () {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var MyService;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_MyService_) {
    MyService = _MyService_;
  }));

  describe('#send', function () {
    it('exists', function () {
      expect(MyService.save).to.exist;
    });
  });

});
```

but the beforeEach(inject(function (...)...); part of the code causes this error
when I try to run the tests:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) my.test "before each" hook: workFn for "exists" FAILED
        Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Function.prototype.bind.apply')
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Does someone has any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13794

Use a Polyfill for `bind` or Phantom2 or test in Chrome

Comment: I was able to get around this issue using https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-polyfill

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded from Angular 1.5.0 to 1.2.29 and now tests are errors free.